# Can anyone spot the issue with my jQuery code - Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am a very new beginner and have been reading the help forums. All I want to do (For now) is have an image ("mygoal.png") be be displayed in the center of the screen with a smooth transition. I was hoping that the image would be displayed as a glorified popup box which is what brought me to fancybox in the first place.

## EDIT: I am getting the following two errors:

```
1) uncaught referenceerror: jquery is not defined 

2) uncaught typeerro: object #<object> has no method fancybox
```

I am placing all of my code in one document - I hope this is the correct practice for jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<script src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

/* I can't get the below code to work */

    $("a#single_image").click(function(event){

        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600,
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false           

       });

});


</script>

</head>

<body>

<a id="single_image" href="mygoal.png"><img src="mygoal.png" alt=""></a>


</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone see my error in the above code? When I click the image now it just takes me to a new page - but no effect at all.

Thank you for reading,

Evan

Comment: the code looks correct, make sure the libraries are loaded properly? also, do you see any errors in firebug or chrome console?

Comment: why use $("a#single_image")?  i think $("#single_image") works fine, and $("#single_image","body") for large pages.  "body" can be substituted with a containing element selector to further reduce the DOM search size.

Comment: You have to include jquery before fancybox

Comment: I got it working - i was missing this reference:


<script src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you've defined the Fancybox script BEFORE the JQuery Script.

The fancybox script is using JQuery methods and as you've not defined JQuery yet, it's causing exceptions:

```
//JQUERY FIRST
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
//FANCYBOX SECOND
<script src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<link href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" />
<script src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" />
```

jQuery needs to be referenced before anything that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working - I was just missing the following reference, unfortunately:

Comment: you HAD that reference, or the pack, minified version at least. You need to read my answer to solve the issue. I think you just defined the new reference UNDERNEATH JQuery, that's why it now works, overwriting the old Fancybox reference.

Comment: It actually worked as soon as i added another reference ... but I'm sure you had a good point as well. Something I will remember for the future. Thank you.

Comment: yeah, my point was that you already had the correct reference in, the second added reference you defined after Jquery, whereas the first was before. Before JQuery = not work. After JQuery = work. The second reference is essentially the same as the first, so all you did was overwrite the first reference, but as you defined it in the correct place, it worked lol

Comment: you are correct. Thank you very much you have no idea how much that helped me ... I went back and what you just said was correct by the way.

Comment: No worries, I remember when I was just starting out with JQuery and always making that mistake! Glad I could help!